# Struct definition

Tags: c, struct, embedded, chibios

I have run into a weird code

```
static ROMCONST struct testcase * ROMCONST *patterns[] = {
  patternbmk,
  NULL
};
```

This code could be found [here](https://github.com/rusefi/rusefi/blob/master/firmware/development/test/test.c).

What kind of struct definition/declaration is this?

Could someone explain in plain English what does it mean?

Comment: `ROMCONST` seems to be some sort of platform-specific MACRO.

Comment: The weirdest part for me is `struct testcase * ROMCONST *patterns[] = {...}`

Comment: What do you think about `#define ROMCONST   const`? [just some random google search](http://chibiforge.org/doc/19.1/full_rm/group__port__types.html#ga8883267a1c9ca4a465f53b8030f1deb3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `ROMCONST`:

As far as we are concerned for understanding these declarations, `ROMCONST` is just some noise macro used in place of `const`.

Such defines are common in embedded systems where you sometimes need non-standard stuff in order to allocate data in flash. Harvard architectures in particular are notorious for this, but also 8/16 bit MCUs that might need non-standard `*far` pointers. And finally in case the table is allocated in EEPROM/data flash, it can be updated in run-time despite being read-only, so then we'd want to add `volatile`. All of these things could be hidden inside `ROMCONST`. So we could in theory have something messy and partially non-standard like

```
#define ROMCONST volatile const far PROGMEM
```

(Where `volatile` is from eeprom/data flash, `const` for any kind of flash, `far` for banked memory and `PROGMEM` something used for declaring data in ROM on Harvard MCUs.)

For now, I'll just ignore this and replace it with `const`.

---

To understand the `const`-qualifiers of the rest of the code, start with the pointed-at arrays like `patternbmk`.

```
const struct testcase * const patternbmk[] = {
```

Picking this apart:

- `struct testcase *  patternbmk[]` declares an array of pointers to structs.
- `const struct testcase * patternbmk[]` gives those pointers read-only access. The pointed-at data is `const` and can't be modified through these pointers.
- `const struct testcase * const patternbmk[]` makes the pointers themselves read-only,  which mainly serves the purpose of ensuring that the table is allocated in flash rather than RAM.

It might be helpful to adapt a coding style such as `*const`, writing the pointer declaration and its qualifier together.

---

Next up the programmer wished to declare an array of pointers to these pointer arrays. (As you can tell this is starting to get messy...) There are two ways that can be used to point at a pointer array, either by pointing at the array with an *array pointer* or by pointing at the first item of the array with a pointer-to-pointer. The programmer chose the latter.

The array item is of type `const struct testcase * const` and in order to point at such an item, we add an additional `*` to the right, ending up with `const struct testcase * const *`. It is helpful to read messy declarations like this from right to left: pointer to const-pointer to const struct testcase.

And then they wished to make an array of such pointer-to-pointers, simply add a `[]` to the end: `const struct testcase * const *patterns[]`.

Not that each initializer in this array implicitly "decays" into a pointer to the first item, so the intializer `patternbmk` decays into `&patternmk[0]` which happens to be a pointer to const-pointer to const struct testcase, same type as I discussed above.

And finally the `static` qualifier is just there to limit variable scope to the file  where it is declared. NULL at the end of the `patterns` initializer list is a sentinel value, marking the end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

The `ROMCONST` most probably a compiler directive and it could be something like this: `#define ROMCONST const` what force the variable to code memory section.

The `patterns` is a struct of array which stores another struct of array `patternbmk` which contains function pointers with the definition of `testcase` struct.

```
static ROMCONST struct testcase * ROMCONST *patterns[] = {
  patternbmk,
  NULL
};

ROMCONST struct testcase * ROMCONST patternbmk[] = {
#if !TEST_NO_BENCHMARKS
  &testbmk1,
  &testbmk2,
  &testbmk3,
  &testbmk4,
  &testbmk5,
  &testbmk6,
  &testbmk7,
  &testbmk8,
#if CH_USE_QUEUES
  &testbmk9,
#endif
  &testbmk10,
#if CH_USE_SEMAPHORES
  &testbmk11,
#endif
#if CH_USE_MUTEXES
  &testbmk12,
#endif
  &testbmk13,
#endif
  NULL
};

ROMCONST struct testcase testbmk1 = {
  "Benchmark, messages #1",
  NULL,
  NULL,
  bmk1_execute
};

struct testcase {
  const char *name;             /**< @brief Test case name.                 */
  void (*setup)(void);          /**< @brief Test case preparation function. */
  void (*teardown)(void);       /**< @brief Test case clean up function.    */
  void (*execute)(void);        /**< @brief Test case execution function.   */
};
```

Comment: I don't understand the part `testcase * const`.

Comment: The `testcase` type is `struct`, this is the first struct.

The `testbmk1` is a `const` and the type is `testcase` so the declaration is `const struct testcase testbmk1`. Then the  `patternbmk` is a `const array` which stores pointers to `testbmkX` so the declaration is `const struct testcase * const patternmbk[]`. Finally the `patterns` is also a `const array` which stores pointer of the previous array so the declaration is `const struct testcase * const *patterns[]`

Comment: Shortly the first `const` is refers to the stored data type and the second `const` is the currently declared variable type.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [chibios](/questions/tagged/chibios) tag, some [google search](http://chibiforge.org/doc/19.1/full_rm/group__port__types.html#ga8883267a1c9ca4a465f53b8030f1deb3) shows

> Macro Definition Documentation
>
> ```
> #define ROMCONST   const
> ```
>
> ROM constant modifier.
>
> Note:
>
> It is set to use the "const" keyword in this port.
> Definition at line 63 of file chtypes.h.

Comment: Replacing the `ROMCONST` with `const` we have `static const struct testcase * const *patterns[]`. I don't understand the part `testcase * const` What kind of pointer is this? If this is a legit syntax? Could you use some parenthesis to make it better for me to understand?

Comment: Doesn't explain _why_ they used the macro though - and it isn't particularly relevant to the question.